# fit div content in to page content using offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, offsetheight

If the height of content in div exceeds the height of the main div, we are trying to use offset and adjust the height but in vain. We tried all possible ways with offset top, offset height.

Could any one help us to get the the correct way to handle. We want to avoid the line being half visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
 body {background-color:white; font:16px Helvetica, Arial; color:black;}
.pagination {margin:auto; display:block; height:275px; width:300px; position:relative;      overflow:hidden; border:1px solid black;}
 </style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//$('.pagination').children().wrapAll('<div class="content"/>');
$('.next').click(function() {
    //console.log($('.content'));
    var height = 10;
    var displayHeight = $('.pagination').height();


    var contentNode = $('.content')[0];

    var currentDisplayHeight = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<contentNode.childNodes.length; i++)
    {
        var currentNode = contentNode.childNodes[i];
        //If it is not a text node
        if(currentNode.nodeType != 3)
        {
            //console.log(currentNode.offsetHeight > displayHeight);
            currentDisplayHeight = currentDisplayHeight + currentNode.offsetHeight;
            console.log(currentDisplayHeight);
            //passing current page
            if(currentDisplayHeight > displayHeight)
            {
                console.log(currentNode);
                console.log("Passing");
                //page 2
                currentDisplayHeight = currentNode.offsetHeight;

            }
        }
    }

    var current = ($('.content').css('margin-top') || '0px');
    //for(i=0; i<pag.
    $('.content').css('margin-top',current.substring(0,current.length-2) - $('.pagination').height() + 'px');
});
});


 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="page" class="pagination" style="padding:5px">
<div class="content">
    <p>The House of Representatives shall be composed of Members chosen every second Year by the People of the several States, and the Electors in each State shall have the Qualifications requisite for Electors of the most numerous Branch of the State Legislature.</p>
    <p>No Person shall be a Representative who shall not have attained to the Age of twenty five Years, and been seven Years a Citizen of the United States, and who shall not, when elected, be an Inhabitant of that State in which he shall be chosen.</p>
    <p>(Representatives and direct Taxes shall be apportioned among the several States which may be included within this Union, according to their respective Numbers, which shall be determined by adding to the whole Number of free Persons, including those bound to Service for a Term of Years, and excluding Indians not taxed, three fifths of all other Persons.) (The previous sentence in parentheses was modified by the 14th Amendment, section 2.) The actual Enumeration shall be made within three Years after the first Meeting of the <span id="c" onclick="clk()">Congress</span> of the United States, and within every subsequent Term of ten Years, in such Manner as they shall by Law direct. The Number of Representatives shall not exceed one for every thirty Thousand, but each State shall have at Least one Representative; and until such enumeration shall be made, the State of New Hampshire shall be entitled to chuse three, Massachusetts eight, Rhode Island and Providence Plantations one, Connecticut five, New York six, New Jersey four, Pennsylvania eight, Delaware one, Maryland six, Virginia ten, North Carolina five, South Carolina five and Georgia three.</p>
    <p>When vacancies happen in the Representation from any State, the Executive Authority thereof shall issue Writs of Election to fill such Vacancies.</p>
    <p>The House of Representatives shall chuse their Speaker and other Officers; and shall have the sole Power of Impeachment.</p>
</div>
   </div>
    <ul>
    <li>Previous</li>
    <li class="next">Next</li>
<li><a href="" onclick="return test()">Click</a></li>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you provide some of your code?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: please find the above sample code

Comment: what do you mean by adjusting the height?

Comment: I meant like to avoid the line which is being cut. I need to move it up or down and fit(.content) exactly with in the main div.(.pagination)

Answer (score 0):

Your content are too big for size 300 X 275px.
To wrap content either you have to decrease font size or 
change CSS

```
 .pagination{height:AUTO;}
```